# Make an AS3 game dynamic with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionscript-3

I am building a game in Flash. I am building a web application in Rails. What I want to do is have Flash be the UI for the game but have Rails serve up all the data, AS3 just communicate with Rails and have Rails manage the data and database etc.

I'm just starting this so I'm looking for resources where people have taken flash apps hopefully games and have used Rails as the backend to store the data as users play the game. Manage data, users, etc.

So to answer this question I just looking for a good resource that goes over dynamically using a Rails web app as the backend for a flash game/app connecting with AS3, JS, Ruby, or whatever. I want Rails to take care of all db stuff. Flash only for UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rough idea you could look at using REST with Rails and Flash frontend, which will allow you to have flash communicate with Rails.

For a brief discussion on this you can look at:
http://railsontherun.com/2007/04/09/rails-and-flash/

Comment: THis is now the way I want to go. I just don't now enough about flash. In that tutorial they say add some code to a fla file. How can I do that?

Comment: For some history you may find this of interest, as to whether to use a .fla file. http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art57468.asp

Answer (score 1):

[WebORB for Rails](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-rails/overview.html) ... They have their own tutorials and link to others

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Thanks